# How setup SSL node.js app server with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, https

I have node.js app that runs in `https://localhost:8080` and it has `localhost.crt` and `localhost.key` i want set server with nginx redirect to `https://app.example.com` (i have installed another certificate with certbot on this sub domain) now im getting

> Unknown ALPN Protocol, expected h2 to be available.If this is a HTTP request: The server was not configured with the allowHTTP1 option or a listener for the unknownProtocol event.

in browser, can someone help me with correct nginx server config? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oltC.jpg)
 also i'm using Digitalocean Droplets with ubuntu 16.04 to setup this
here is nginx server i have set.

```
server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443;
server_name app.mydomain.com;

ssl_certificate           /root/apps/app.mydomain.com/localhost.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /root/apps/app.mydomain.com/localhost.key;

ssl on;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;

location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          https://localhost:8080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  proxy_redirect      https://localhost:8080 https://app.mydomain.com;
}
}
```

Comment: You don't mention whether you have tried anything on your own yet...there are a lot of tutorials out there. For example I googled "nginx reverse proxy ssl node.js", found quite a few good tutorials, including for example [this one](https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/). If you've already tried a tutorial, it would be good to include what you've done thus far, what error(s) or problems you've encountered, and some information on your current configuration.

Answer (score -1):

This:

`listen 443;`

Should be this:

`listen 443 ssl;`

Why do you want to proxy traffic to 127.0.0.1 via https? Seems unnecessary

Comment: the app is not editable this is only problem it has to be https

Comment: it still does not solve this response, it is the same error about the main question

Answer (score -1):

Try this configuration, Hope it works. All the headers are not required it's based on your applications need and how you are serving the requests fro your application.

```
server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443;
server_name app.mydomain.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate_key       /root/apps/app.mydomain.com/localhost.key;
ssl_certificate           /root/apps/app.mydomain.com/localhost.crt;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;

location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k; 
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
}
}
```